# missing directive or assembly reference?

Tags: forms, list, using-directives

I am trying to recompile an application but I am getting this error:

Error   10  The type or namespace name 'SettingItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Documents and Settings\Haseeb\Desktop\mo\IMLockInterface\Form1.cs    338 22  IMLockInterface

Its a list

Here is the source code

```
namespace IMLockInterface
{
using IMLockInterface.IMLockLogin;
using IMLockInterface.My;
using IMLockInterface.My.Resources;
using IMLockTree;
using libqclient;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
using MlRuntime;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerGenerated]
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private static List<WeakReference> __ENCList = new List<WeakReference>();
    [AccessedThroughProperty("AboutToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _AboutToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ActivateToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _ActivateToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("BlockingToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _BlockingToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("BlockTabpage")]
    private TabPage _BlockTabpage;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("BlockToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _BlockToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("btnAddSession")]
    private Button _btnAddSession;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("btnAddSetting")]
    private Button _btnAddSetting;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("btnClearAllsession")]
    private Button _btnClearAllsession;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("btnDownloadforEdit")]
    private Button _btnDownloadforEdit;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("btnRemoveSession")]
    private Button _btnRemoveSession;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("btnRemoveSetting")]
    private Button _btnRemoveSetting;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("btnResettoOriginal")]
    private Button _btnResettoOriginal;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("btnSetAsDefault")]
    private Button _btnSetAsDefault;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("btnUpdateSetting")]
    private Button _btnUpdateSetting;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("chkBlockAllOthers")]
    private CheckBox _chkBlockAllOthers;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("chkBlockMSConfig")]
    private CheckBox _chkBlockMSConfig;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("chkBlockRegistry")]
    private CheckBox _chkBlockRegistry;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("chkBlockTaskMGR")]
    private CheckBox _chkBlockTaskMGR;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("chkIMLockOn")]
    private CheckBox _chkIMLockOn;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("chkShowNotification")]
    private CheckBox _chkShowNotification;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ColumnHeader_Current")]
    private ColumnHeader _ColumnHeader_Current;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ColumnHeader1")]
    private ColumnHeader _ColumnHeader1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ColumnHeader2")]
    private ColumnHeader _ColumnHeader2;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ColumnHeader4")]
    private ColumnHeader _ColumnHeader4;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ColumnHeader5")]
    private ColumnHeader _ColumnHeader5;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ColumnHeader6")]
    private ColumnHeader _ColumnHeader6;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ExitToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _ExitToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("FileToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _FileToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("GroupBox1")]
    private GroupBox _GroupBox1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("GroupBox2")]
    private GroupBox _GroupBox2;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("GroupBox3")]
    private GroupBox _GroupBox3;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("GroupBox4")]
    private GroupBox _GroupBox4;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("GroupBox5")]
    private GroupBox _GroupBox5;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("GroupBox6")]
    private GroupBox _GroupBox6;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("HelpToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _HelpToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("HomeTabpage")]
    private TabPage _HomeTabpage;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ImageList_MainTab")]
    private ImageList _ImageList_MainTab;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ImageList_TabIcons")]
    private ImageList _ImageList_TabIcons;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ImageList1")]
    private ImageList _ImageList1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("imLockTree_Blocked")]
    private IMLockTreeCtrl _imLockTree_Blocked;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("imLockTree_Porn")]
    private IMLockTreeCtrl _imLockTree_Porn;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("imLockTree_Programs")]
    private IMLockTreeCtrl _imLockTree_Programs;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("imLockTree_Whitelist")]
    private IMLockTreeCtrl _imLockTree_Whitelist;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("label_SaveAlert")]
    private Label _label_SaveAlert;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label1")]
    private Label _Label1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label10")]
    private Label _Label10;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label11")]
    private Label _Label11;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label12")]
    private Label _Label12;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label14")]
    private Label _Label14;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label15")]
    private Label _Label15;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label16")]
    private Label _Label16;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label17")]
    private Label _Label17;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label18")]
    private Label _Label18;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label19")]
    private Label _Label19;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label2")]
    private Label _Label2;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label20")]
    private Label _Label20;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label21")]
    private Label _Label21;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label22")]
    private Label _Label22;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label23")]
    private Label _Label23;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label25")]
    private Label _Label25;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label3")]
    private Label _Label3;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label4")]
    private Label _Label4;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label5")]
    private Label _Label5;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label6")]
    private Label _Label6;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label7")]
    private Label _Label7;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label8")]
    private Label _Label8;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Label9")]
    private Label _Label9;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lblRegDaysRemaining")]
    private Label _lblRegDaysRemaining;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lblRegEmail")]
    private Label _lblRegEmail;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lblRegLicense")]
    private Label _lblRegLicense;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lblRegName")]
    private Label _lblRegName;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lblReportsTitle")]
    private Label _lblReportsTitle;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("LinkLabel_Reports")]
    private LinkLabel _LinkLabel_Reports;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("LinkLabel1")]
    private LinkLabel _LinkLabel1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("LinkLabel2_SubscribeNow")]
    private LinkLabel _LinkLabel2_SubscribeNow;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lstDefaultSettingsSel")]
    private ListView _lstDefaultSettingsSel;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lstSavedSettings")]
    private ListView _lstSavedSettings;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lstSchedules")]
    private ListView _lstSchedules;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lvScheduleDayCol")]
    private ColumnHeader _lvScheduleDayCol;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lvScheduleEndCol")]
    private ColumnHeader _lvScheduleEndCol;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lvScheduleStartCol")]
    private ColumnHeader _lvScheduleStartCol;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("MenuStrip1")]
    private MenuStrip _MenuStrip1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("NetworkingToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _NetworkingToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("NetworkTabPage")]
    private TabPage _NetworkTabPage;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("networkTabsImageList")]
    private ImageList _networkTabsImageList;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("NotifyTabPage")]
    private TabPage _NotifyTabPage;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("NotifyToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _NotifyToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("OptionsToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _OptionsToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Panel1")]
    private Panel _Panel1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("PatternsTabPage")]
    private TabPage _PatternsTabPage;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("PatternToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _PatternToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("pictureBox_SaveAlert")]
    private PictureBox _pictureBox_SaveAlert;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("PictureBox1")]
    private PictureBox _PictureBox1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("PictureBox2")]
    private PictureBox _PictureBox2;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("PornTabPage")]
    private TabPage _PornTabPage;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("PornToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _PornToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ProgramsTabPage")]
    private TabPage _ProgramsTabPage;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ProgramsToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _ProgramsToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("rdBlockingExact")]
    private RadioButton _rdBlockingExact;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("rdBlockingPattern")]
    private RadioButton _rdBlockingPattern;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("rdProgramsExact")]
    private RadioButton _rdProgramsExact;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("rdProgramsPattern")]
    private RadioButton _rdProgramsPattern;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("rdWhitelistExact")]
    private RadioButton _rdWhitelistExact;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("rdWhitelistPattern")]
    private RadioButton _rdWhitelistPattern;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Redirect")]
    private TabPage _Redirect;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("RedirectToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _RedirectToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ReportsTabPage")]
    private TabPage _ReportsTabPage;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ReportToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _ReportToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("resetTabPage")]
    private TabPage _resetTabPage;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ResetTabToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _ResetTabToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("SaveToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _SaveToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("schedulesImageList")]
    private ImageList _schedulesImageList;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ScheduleTabPage")]
    private TabPage _ScheduleTabPage;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ScheduleToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _ScheduleToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("settingsListViewImageList")]
    private ImageList _settingsListViewImageList;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("StatusStrip1")]
    private StatusStrip _StatusStrip1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("SystemTabPage")]
    private TabPage _SystemTabPage;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("SystemToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _SystemToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("TabControl1")]
    private TabControl _TabControl1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("TabControl2")]
    private TabControl _TabControl2;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("TabPage19")]
    private TabPage _TabPage19;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("TabPage20")]
    private TabPage _TabPage20;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStrip1")]
    private ToolStrip _ToolStrip1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStrip2")]
    private ToolStrip _ToolStrip2;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButton1")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButton1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonBlock")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonBlock;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonBlockBlocking")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonBlockBlocking;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonBlockPorn")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonBlockPorn;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonBlockPrograms")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonBlockPrograms;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonBlockSystem")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonBlockSystem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonBlockWhitelist")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonBlockWhitelist;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonHomeSide")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonHomeSide;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonNetwork")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonNetwork;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonNetworkSide")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonNetworkSide;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonOptions")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonOptions;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonOptNotify")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonOptNotify;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonOptPatterns")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonOptPatterns;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonOptRedirect")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonOptRedirect;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonReport")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonReport;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonReportReports")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonReportReports;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonResetSide")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonResetSide;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonSave")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonSave;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonSchedule")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonSchedule;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolStripButtonScheduleScheduler")]
    private ToolStripButton _ToolStripButtonScheduleScheduler;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("txtDescription")]
    private TextBox _txtDescription;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("txtNotifyMsg1")]
    private TextBox _txtNotifyMsg1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("txtNotifyMsg2")]
    private TextBox _txtNotifyMsg2;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("txtNotifyMsg3")]
    private TextBox _txtNotifyMsg3;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("txtRedirectURL")]
    private TextBox _txtRedirectURL;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("txtSettingName")]
    private TextBox _txtSettingName;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("UninstallToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _UninstallToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("UsernameLabel")]
    private Label _UsernameLabel;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ViewToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _ViewToolStripMenuItem;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("WhitelistTabpage")]
    private TabPage _WhitelistTabpage;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("WhitelistToolStripMenuItem")]
    private ToolStripMenuItem _WhitelistToolStripMenuItem;
    public SettingsForGUI applicationData;
    private IContainer components;
    public UserInfo currentUserInfo;
    private bool IsSettingsDataChanged;
    private List<SettingItem> savedSettingsList; //I am getting error here
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should type that namespace IMLockInterface after all headers declarations and use "using SettingItem" after adding its reference to current project.

Comment: Did it but still same result.. I guess typing after or before dont mean any change

Comment: is your problem solved.....if not, remove that reference then try to rebuild that assembly reference project again and add as reference to your project again, and rebuilt entire thing.....